# Github feature branch made branches automatically and merged it again

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-push

If you see the picture below, the blue branch is a `feature branch` *Dev A* and *Dev B* are working on. No one has branched off of the feature branch. But when *Dev B* removed some files, committed and pushed the changes to repo, it was created as a branch of the `feature branch` in git client graphical view (sourcetree). When *Dev B* checks `git status`, it still says the working branch is the same `feature branch`.

*Dev A* created some service class, committed and pushed it. It shows it still is in the `feature branch`. Why does this exactly happen, anyone can help explain please? Is it just graphical? Or either *Dev A* or *Dev B* didn't pull a change in between. Additionaly, on next `git push` by *Dev B*, the red new branch merged back to the feature branch.

Upon request, here is the `git log` of *Dev B*:

```
* af335d1 added...
*   63fa2a2 Merge branch 'feature-branch' of github.devops.abcCorp.local:namespace/project into feature-branch
|\  
| * c8d62c1 removed...
* | 74456c5 created...
|/  
* b321f9a fixed...
* 97d7c33 added...
```

[image: git-feature-branch-conflict]

Comment: I have a suspicion what happened, but there's not enough information. `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` would be more useful than a picture. And from both devA, devB's POV please.

Comment: just did. didnt realize that comments wont' be effective earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened is *Dev A* tried to push, but it got rejected, so (s)he pulled and then pushed successfully.

A `pull` is equivalent to a `fetch` and a `merge`. For example, if you are on `feature_branch`:

```
git pull origin feature_branch
```

is equivalent to

```
git fetch
git merge origin/feature_branch
```

The reason there's a branch in the log is that, since *Dev A*'s local branch diverged from the remote branch, a fast-forward merge was not possible and git had to create a merge commit.

You can avoid this by using `git pull --rebase` to reapply your local commits on top of the remote branch.

```
              |  local feature_branch           remote reature_branch
--------------|------------------------------------------------------
before        | A--B--C                        A--B--D
              |
pull          | A--B--C--M
              |        \ /
              |         D
              |
pull --rebase | A--B--D--C'
```

Comment: In what case is a fast-forward merge impossible?

Comment: When the current branch head is not an ancestor of the branch to be merged. ([Fast-forwad merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge))